# Emulate/Pass-through Physical NIC on Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 for VM

Tags: hyper-v, nic

We recently re-did a client's server and set it up as a VM. However, they use a license server for one of their products and the license server doesn't work on a VM. I asked their support team as to why it doesn't work, and their response was " [The software] is looking for a physical NIC card".

Now, I'm looking for ways to get around this. I don't believe that professional software released in 2017 shouldn't support VMs, since virtualized environments are so prevalent. I don't believe it's possible to pass though a physical NIC to a VM on Hyper-V Core (but if so, please explain), but I don't think it should be too hard to emulate or otherwise 'fake' a 'real' card. Is there any way I can do such a thing, or otherwise get around this NIC issue?

Comment: If the software isn't supported in a VM, then when it breaks and you are on a VM it is going to be unsupported. That will suck for you.  RE: `I don't believe it's possible to pass though a physical NIC` - Look for SRV-IO support https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-root_input/output_virtualization

Comment: Indeed, but their support is paid anyways, and we don't really need it. Thanks for the link, I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try adding a "Legacy Network adapter" to your VM.  This will create an emulation of a (very old) PCI-based NIC.  This may or may not convince the licensing software that things are copacetic.

Performance of this emulation will leave a lot to be desired.  If possibly, make sure that this isn't the NIC that you actually want traffic to flow through.

Answer (score 0):

Some reading on how to assign a physical device (NIC, GPU and related) to a VM may be found at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/blob/master/WindowsServerDocs/virtualization/hyper-v/plan/Plan-for-Deploying-Devices-using-Discrete-Device-Assignment.md.